# PHP script require "anotherscript.php" running too long?

Tags: php, require

Hi I have a php script below that runs too long due to long running requirement of `require "anotherscript.php"`

How do i dissociate/stop this current php file process once the remaining operation can be pass to anotherscript.php to run along with essential variables like $path, $picture or others?

However, doing this I also have another concern such that when `anotherscript.php` having not run finish, but since user has been notified 'uploaded_success' he would upload another picture thus, causing another issue. Is there a way to solve the above mentioned issues? Thank You

```
if(file_put_contents($path, base64_decode($picture)) != false){
        echo "uploaded_success";
        require "anotherscript.php";
    }
    else{
        echo "uploaded_failed";
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can run this script using ajax?

Comment: option 1 (not cross platform but only secure option for frontside delay) : Use webworkers and persistent storage. Option 2: if image, use js to reduce the size of the uploaded file. Option 3: if process runs long on serverside, move process to background with nohup for example.